# Flagging question options seems to have shrunk

Tags: support, flags

I've just gone to flag a question and the list of possible reasons to flag is limited to:

- It needs moderator attention: Other
- It is spam
- It is not welcome in our community

I'm sure the list of reasons for flagging a post used to be much more fine grained (I'm pretty sure it included "Low Quality Posts" which is what I was going for).  Has anything changed?

Comment: Nothing changed. Low quality doesn't show up when the score is positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Oded stated in the comments, the VLQ option doesn't show up for posts with a positive score - as the system figures that they probably aren't VLQ.